# Different environment per Behat context (Symfony 4.x)

Tags: php, symfony, testing, yaml, behat

I want to create a lot of Behat features with simulating different configurations (from yaml,xml,php files).

Official extension for support Symfony 4 - [Symfony2Extension](https://github.com/Behat/Symfony2Extension) have support for configuring a different environment like:

```
default:
    # ...
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
               class: App\Kernel
               bootstrap: config/bootstrap.php
               env: custom_env
```

But, this extension is loaded before any suites or context. I should initial Kernel for each separate context with different config files via env.

Like:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                params:
                    env: custom_env
                - FeatureContext:
```

or

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                    env: custom_env
```

And I'll load Kernel manually inside Context.

Any idea here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could define different profiles for each env:

```
default:
  # ...
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension:
        kernel:
           class: App\Kernel
           bootstrap: config/bootstrap.php

php_profile:
  # ...
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension:
        kernel:
           env: prod

yaml_profile:
  # ...
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension:
        kernel:
           env: dev
```